# NHibernate making too much queries, about mapping using idBag correctly

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, mapping

We're developing an application using NHibernate, C# .NET, and we're in a question about a mapping... Here's the situation:

**First, i'll put our mapping files:**

This is User.hbm.xml mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="GLib.GSecurity.Domain" namespace="Geraes.GLib.GSecurity.Domain" >

<typedef class="uNhAddIns.UserTypes.EncryptedString, uNhAddIns" name="Encrypted">
  <param name="encryptor">uNhAddIns.UserTypes.uNHAddinsEncryptor, uNhAddIns</param>
  <param name="encryptionKey">myRGBKey</param>
</typedef>

<class name="User" table="S_User" lazy="false" dynamic-update="true">

<id name="Id" column="Id_User" type="Int64">
  <generator class="Geraes.GLib.GDomainBasis.CustomTableHiLoGenerator, GLib.GDomainBasis" />
</id>

<many-to-one name="Plant" column="Id_Plant" class="Plant"
             foreign-key="fk1_User" cascade="none" fetch="join" not-null="true"/>

<property name="Login" column="Login" type="String" length="16" not-null="true" />

<property name="Password" column="Password" type="Encrypted" />

<property name="Name" column="Name" type="String" length="64" not-null="true" />

<property name="Active" column="Active" type="Char" not-null="true" />

 <idbag name="RightProfiles" table="S_User_Right_Profile" generic="true" lazy="false" cascade="save-update" fetch="join">
   <collection-id type="Int64" column="Id_User_Right_Profile">
     <generator class="Geraes.GLib.GDomainBasis.CustomTableHiLoGenerator, GLib.GDomainBasis" />
   </collection-id>
   <key column="Id_User" />
   <many-to-many column="Id_Right_Profile" class="RightProfile" fetch="join"/>
 </idbag>

  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

This is RightProfile.hbm.xml mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="GLib.GSecurity.Domain" namespace="Geraes.GLib.GSecurity.Domain" >

  <class name="RightProfile" table="S_Right_Profile" lazy="false" dynamic-update="true">

    <id name="Id" column="Id_Right_Profile" type="Int64">
      <generator class="Geraes.GLib.GDomainBasis.CustomTableHiLoGenerator, GLib.GDomainBasis" />
    </id>

    <property name="Name" column="Name" type="String" length="20" not-null="true" />

    <property name="Description" column="Description" type="String" length="60" not-null="true" />

    <idbag name="Resources" table="S_Right_Profile_Resource" generic="true" lazy="false" cascade="save-update" fetch="join">
      <collection-id type="Int64" column="Id_Right_Profile_Resource">
        <generator class="Geraes.GLib.GDomainBasis.CustomTableHiLoGenerator, GLib.GDomainBasis" />
      </collection-id>
      <key column="Id_Right_Profile" />
      <many-to-many column="Id_Resource" class="Resource" fetch="join"/>
    </idbag>

    <idbag name="Users" table="S_User_Right_Profile" generic="true" inverse="true" lazy="false" cascade="save-update" fetch="join">
      <collection-id type="Int64" column="Id_User_Right_Profile">
        <generator class="Geraes.GLib.GDomainBasis.CustomTableHiLoGenerator, GLib.GDomainBasis" />
      </collection-id>
      <key column="Id_Right_Profile" />
      <many-to-many column="Id_User" class="User" fetch="join"/>
    </idbag>

  </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Now, our entity class:**

User.cs entity class:

```
public class User : BaseEntityEditable
{
    public virtual Plant Plant { get; set; }

    public virtual String Login { get; set; }

    public virtual String Password { get; set; }

    public virtual String Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Char Active { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<RightProfile> RightProfiles { get; set; }

    public override String ToString()
    {
        return Name + " - " + Login;
    }

    public User()
    {
        RightProfiles = new List<RightProfile>();
        Plant = new Plant();
    }
}
```

RightProfile.cs entity class:

```
public class RightProfile : BaseEntityEditable
{
    public virtual String Name { get; set; }

    public virtual String Description { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Resource> Resources { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<User> Users { get; set; }

    public override String ToString()
    {
        return Name + " - " + Description;
    }

    public RightProfile()
    {
        Resources = new List<Resource>();
        Users = new List<User>();
    }
}
```

So, our situation is:

We're developing a Window. In this window, we have 2 grids. A grid for users, and a grid for Groups. 
When this window is loaded, our viewModel start makes the necessary queries to bring data. The first query bring all users, and inside the Users, we have a List of RightProfiles, containing all data necessary to populate our other grid. So far, so good.
Our problem is, nhibernate start making queries, bringing all Users of all RightProfiles.

**He cannot do that!** We already have all data needed!

**-- Edited --**

Our first part is running ok, we search for users, search for RightProfiles (to populate the grid), and then , we mark what user is allowed to, inside that grid. 
In fact, my window works just fine. 
Our problem is, inside Nhibernate Log, he's making an select for each user associated who has an associated Right Profile.

These selects are unnecessary, once the data has already been loaded. This is my problem, nhibernate is doing much more selects that needed to be done.

How i can change this?

**-- Edit 2: --**
Here's the SQL generated by NHibernate Log:

This select is OK:

```
   SELECT
    this_.Id_Right_Profile as Id1_36_3_,
    this_.Name as Name36_3_,
    this_.Description as Descript3_36_3_,
    resources2_.Id_Right_Profile as Id1_5_,
    resource3_.Id_Resource as Id2_5_,
    resources2_.Id_Right_Profile_Resource as Id3_5_,
    resource3_.Id_Resource as Id1_39_0_,
    resource3_.Name as Name39_0_,
    users4_.Id_Right_Profile as Id1_6_,
    user5_.Id_User as Id2_6_,
    users4_.Id_User_Right_Profile as Id3_6_,
    user5_.Id_User as Id1_42_1_,
    user5_.Id_Plant as Id2_42_1_,
    user5_.Login as Login42_1_,
    user5_.Password as Password42_1_,
    user5_.Name as Name42_1_,
    user5_.Active as Active42_1_,
    plant6_.Id_Plant as Id1_41_2_,
    plant6_.Name as Name41_2_,
    plant6_.Description as Descript3_41_2_ 
FROM
    S_Right_Profile this_ 
left outer join
    S_Right_Profile_Resource resources2_ 
        on this_.Id_Right_Profile=resources2_.Id_Right_Profile 
left outer join
    S_Resource resource3_ 
        on resources2_.Id_Resource=resource3_.Id_Resource 
left outer join
    S_User_Right_Profile users4_ 
        on this_.Id_Right_Profile=users4_.Id_Right_Profile 
left outer join
    S_User user5_ 
        on users4_.Id_User=user5_.Id_User 
left outer join
    S_Plant plant6_ 
        on user5_.Id_Plant=plant6_.Id_Plant 
ORDER BY
    this_.Name asc
```

This select, in my view, is unnecessary (**it repeats for each user**):

```
SELECT
    rightprofi0_.Id_User as Id2_1_,
    rightprofi0_.Id_Right_Profile as Id1_1_,
    rightprofi0_.Id_User_Right_Profile as Id3_1_,
    rightprofi1_.Id_Right_Profile as Id1_36_0_,
    rightprofi1_.Name as Name36_0_,
    rightprofi1_.Description as Descript3_36_0_ 
FROM
    S_User_Right_Profile rightprofi0_ 
left outer join
    S_Right_Profile rightprofi1_ 
        on rightprofi0_.Id_Right_Profile=rightprofi1_.Id_Right_Profile 
WHERE
    rightprofi0_.Id_User=:p0;
:p0 = 10807 [Type: Int64 (0)]
```

Comment: Are you sure your `GetHashCode` and `Equals` method is properly implemented.

Comment: are you usinh linqtonh or hql? you should shape the query to fetch what you need in order to avoi the select n+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting a batch size on your idBag?

```
 <idbag batch-size='50' .. >
```

You may want to play around with the actual value to get the best performance.

BTW in your example setting a `batch-size` of 50 will reduce your queries to 3.

**edit after your edit**
Your idBag in the RightProfile xml has `fetch="join"` defined.  A "fetch" join allows associations or collections of values to be initialized along with their parent objects using a single select.

What happens if you change the fetch strategy to select?

```
<idbag name="Users" table="S_User_Right_Profile" lazy="true" fetch="select".. .
```

Comment: Rippo, i'll edit my question, i didn't make a clear question... This window works fine, all data is loaded perfectly. But, looking inside my logs, shows to me than nhibernate is making a query for each user associated for each RightProfile. These selects are unnecessary, once the data has already been loaded. This is my problem, nhibernate is doing much more selects that needed to be done.

Comment: So you are saying users are being loaded twice, once for grid then because users are related to RightProfile?

Comment: Yes. When this window loads, it runs a query to bring info from User and RightProfile. Inside User, we have a List of RightProfiles than carries which RightProfiles Users belongs. Until that, it's ok. But NHibernate does a lot of query after that, seeking which user is related to an RightProfile.

Comment: Rippo, i've tested the fetch="select" option, now makes more search.. with fetch=join, NHibernate only did the queries, searching for users which it's associated to that RightProfile. Now, it searches all Users to all RightProfile.

Comment: I take it you didn't see that I changed `fetch="select"` and `lazy="true"` in my edit! I am sorry you failed to see this.

Comment: Ops! Hehehe I really didn't see it. Voted as valid response!!

Comment: For the late readers: the huge join clause above does not only fetch unneccessary data, but also multiply the number of results with each additional join level. It will likely create a huge cartesian product of the results.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Just set the lazy option to true, now NHibernate doesn't execute those extra-selects

=D

Thanks everyone!